# How do I display the Bluetooth headphone icon on an iPhone Xs?

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth

I've moved from an iPhone 8 to and XS and have noticed the little headphone icon no longer appears up near the battery icon when I connect to bluetooth headphones.

Is there a way to bring this back?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at the screen, you might not see the icon. But if you pull down the control center by swiping down from the top right, you should see the headphone icon when your bluetooth headphones are connected.

To answer the question, no. There is no way of bringing it back to the home screen.